# Classic ASP error line 0 column -1

Tags: iis, asp-classic

We run a busy website built on classic ASP (for all sorts of legacy reasons). During busy periods we're seeing an unexplained error and can't get to the bottom of it. It manifests by IIS 7 triggering our custom 500 error page.

On this page we gather as much detail about the error as we can, using both the ASPError object and the err object. What we emerge with is:

From the ASPError object:

---

ASPCode: 0

Category:

Source:

Page:

Description:

Line: 0

Column: -1

---

In the err object, err.Number, err.Source and err.Description are all empty.

I don't know whether to look further for IIS configuration issues, application pools etc. or whether this is a code-related problem.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the first couple lines of code?

Comment: Hi Artem, the error itself appears to get triggered from just about any page - it doesn't seem related to a specific bit of code, leading me to think that it might be an IIS config or similar. Line 0, column -1 just sounds odd! I can post code of our custom 500 error page which generates the error details if that would help?

Comment: In IIS settings are ASP errors being sent to client?

Comment: They're not! Shall I change "Send Errors To Browser" in IIS > ASP > Compilation to true and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, make sure it's sending errors to browser, http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/564/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default/ It should give a more detailed error message.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, will do that and see what it tells us.

Comment: Do you have a Global.asa file for this application?

Comment: Tom, I'm not getting any more detail coming through to the client - does the change require an IIS restart? However good news is at the same time I set IIS to record errors to the NT Log and via the event viewer I can see a specific issue ([Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.) which is not making its way to our error reporting. We're going to resolve that and see if it stops the line 0, column -1 problem as perhaps they are one and the same. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: No Global.asa for the application.

Comment: @Andy nobody saw your comments here, use `@` to notify people when you comment e.g. @Tom will notify "Tom Gullen".

Comment: Anyway, post the relevant code where you Open the connection and we'll continue helping from that point.

Comment: @AndyW have you had any luck solving this problem? if you have can you please post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple separate ASP page that would trigger an error. For example :

```
<%
Option Explicit
a = 1
%>
```

Browse to the page and see what happens. If you still got no error informations it is probably IIS configuration. Otherwise you may have some really curious error, but nothing I've ever seen in the past.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late on my reply, hopefully you have solved this by now and this will simply help someone else in our position later.

In IIS, open the site and then the Error Pages feature.  Select "Edit Feature Settings..." from the right side and change to "Detailed errors".  Refresh the page throwing the error and you should see the true error which is occurring.

I had 2 errors which could cause this: missing DB Provider and using Option Explicit with an undeclared variable.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

In IIS7 and later, there's a bug whereby only the default error handler gets full error details - if you call Server.GetLastError() from a custom error page that's configured for a specific error code, everything comes back blank.

There is a workaround, though - if you set the site’s default error property (under IIS settings > Error Pages > Edit Feature Settings...) to your custom error page, IIS will invoke this page whenever an error is not handled by an explicitly configured status-code handler (so your 404, etc. handlers will still work) - but for some reason, handling the error this way means Server.GetLastError() still works properly

More details at
https://dylanbeattie.net/2008/12/04/fun-with-servergetlasterror-in-classic.html

Comment: A shame you didn't put the details into this answer, as the linked page no longer exists. :-(

Comment: It does... there was a broken link in the redirect chain (that site's been migrated five times since 2008, when the article was written!)

Link should be working again now - the post is at https://dylanbeattie.net/2008/12/04/fun-with-servergetlasterror-in-classic.html in case it doesn't.

Comment: Ah, okay nice.  Another way to do it (which I just did after much hair-pulling) is to set a custom error page as target for a 500.100 error. Classic ASP doesn’t just sent 500, it sends 500.100, and for whatever reason `Server.GetLastError()` works if the page is called that way

Comment: @StephenR ...ooh – interesting. Nice work. Wish I'd known about that back in 2008. :)